# Bootstrap 4 sticky-top

Tags: bootstrap-4, shopify

I've been trying to get the navbar on my site to stick to the top of my page when scrolling, but I can't seem to get it to stay. It seems like it stays there for a just a moment when scrolling, then drops off. Any thoughts? Here's the site:  https://katanasakana.com/ And the relevant code:

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="border-right">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{shop.url}}">
    <img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_img_url: 'large'}}" height="60" alt="Katana Sakana">
  </a>
  </div>

  <div style=" padding-right: 40px;">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="text-align:center; font-weight:550">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-primary" href="{{shop.url}}" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Shop<br>「ショップ」
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://katanasakana.com/collections/anime">Anime T-Shirts</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://katanasakana.com/collections/sweaters">Sweaters & Hoodies</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://katanasakana.com/collections/martial-arts">Martial Arts</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://katanasakana.com/collections/city-and-prefectural-crests">Japanese Crests</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-primary" href="https://katanasakana.com/pages/about-us">About Us<br>「ストーリー」</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-primary" href="https://katanasakana.com/pages/sizing-chart">Size Guide<br>「サイズガイド」</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-primary" href="https://katanasakana.com/blogs/news/"> Blog<br>「ブログ」</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div style="margin-right:5%">
   <a href="/cart" class="text-dark">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart 2x"></i>
      {{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}
      ({{ cart.item_count }} {{ 'layout.cart.items_count' | t: count: cart.item_count }})
   </a>
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Naruto, One Piece..." aria-label="Search" name="q" value="{{ search.terms | escape }}">
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product" />
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly? in the link you provided I see the navbar sticks to the top, but since it has no background color defined it is transparent and overlaps awfully with the content

Comment: Thank you! I've been changing this on the fly thanks to i.G.'s message below and wasn't sure why it was doing that - but now that I've made the background a solid colour it's working much better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code representing the nav tag has no problem, bat the position of nav tag in the page is not correct, it's has to be in a container that have the full height of body, because the nav tag behavior is correct in the div#shopify-section-header but because of minimal height of this container you can't see that it work.

I propose that you put sticky-top to div#shopify-section-header or put the nav tag out of your div#shopify-section-header and it will work correctly

I hope this help you, good work by the way :)

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to move the elements around it seems to be working now! :)